# efficient method for merging 2 sorted files with duplicate coordinates in python

Tags: python, merge, duplicates, coordinates, sorting

I am relatively new to Python, and trying use it to merge two sorted files which contain 4 columns:

file 1:

```
x-coordinate, y-coordinate, data 1, data 2  
1, 10, 20, 0  
5, 15, 1, 2  
...
```

file 2:

```
x-coordinate, y-coordinate, data 3, data 4  
1, 10, 7, 8  
3, 25, 1, 2  
...
```

into a single sorted file with 6 columns which contain each unique set of (x,y) coordinates:

```
x-coordinate, y-coordinate, data 1, data 2, data 3, data 4  
1, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8  
3, 25, 0, 0, 1, 2  
5, 15, 1, 2, 0, 0
```

I think this task would be trivial using dictionaries if only the order of the output file didn't matter. As my input files are 100s of lines long, I am trying to come up with an efficient 'pythonic' way of handling the duplicate cases (i.e., where the same (x,y) coordinates are present in both files), but so far I am stumped.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not following what you're looking for with regard to duplicates.  You act like you don't want duplicates, but then you have `1, 10, 20, 0` in the output?  Also, how are the files sorted?  One thing you could do is sort the dictionaries items just before you output it.

Comment: "If only the order of the output file didn't matter". How about using dictionaries to write the file, an then performing a sort after the fact? If you only have a few hundred lines, resorting won't take long.

Comment: Are these files "sorted" by increasing x-coordinate and then increasing y-coordinate when the x-coordinates are the same? Or are they "sorted" only in the sense that order is important and must be preserved?

Comment: The coordinates (1, 10) appear in both files. In file 1 the data is [20, 0], in file 2 the output is [7, 8]. I am trying to merge the data from each file into a single line: 1, 10, 20, 0, 7, 8. For coordinates without duplicates, I'll simply fill in the missing data with 0s.

Comment: Files are sorted by increasing x, then by increasing y. Sorry, I should've been clearer about that.

Comment: Also: the individual files may be only 100s of lines long, but I need to merge ~ 1000 file pairs. Thus the aversion to dictionaries, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("coord1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("coord2.csv")
combined = df1.merge(df2, how='outer').fillna(0)
combined.sort(list(combined.columns[:2]), inplace=True)
combined.to_csv("coord_merged.csv",index=False)
```

---

First, read in the original data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv("coord1.csv")
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv("coord2.csv")
>>> df1
   x-coordinate   y-coordinate   data 1   data 2
0             1             10       20        0
1             5             15        1        2
>>> df2
   x-coordinate   y-coordinate   data 3   data 4  
0             1             10        7          8
1             3             25        1          2
```

Merge them, and fill the missing data with zeros:

```
>>> combined = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
>>> combined
   x-coordinate   y-coordinate   data 1   data 2   data 3   data 4  
0             1             10       20        0        7          8
1             5             15        1        2      NaN        NaN
2             3             25      NaN      NaN        1          2
>>> combined = df1.merge(df2, how='outer').fillna(0)
>>> combined
   x-coordinate   y-coordinate   data 1   data 2   data 3   data 4  
0             1             10       20        0        7          8
1             5             15        1        2        0          0
2             3             25        0        0        1          2
```

Sort:

```
>>> combined.sort(list(combined.columns[:2]), inplace=True)
>>> combined
   x-coordinate   y-coordinate   data 1   data 2   data 3   data 4  
0             1             10       20        0        7          8
2             3             25        0        0        1          2
1             5             15        1        2        0          0
```

And finally write out:

```
>>> combined.to_csv("coord_merged.csv",index=False)
>>> !cat coord_merged.csv
x-coordinate, y-coordinate, data 1, data 2, data 3, data 4  
1.0,10.0,20.0,0.0,7.0,8.0
3.0,25.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0
5.0,15.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0
```

If keeping to an integer format is important, then

```
>>> combined.astype(int).to_csv("coord_merged.csv",index=False)
>>> !cat coord_merged.csv
x-coordinate, y-coordinate, data 1, data 2, data 3, data 4  
1,10,20,0,7,8
3,25,0,0,1,2
5,15,1,2,0,0
```

would do it.

Comment: is `!cat coord_merged.csv` some kind of "ipython magic"?  Your prompts don't look like ipython prompts.

Comment: @mgilson: yep.  I've wondered if that was going to come up, actually -- I've switched to `ipython --classic` mode because I was confusing people with the `[123]` stuff, but I guess this has the opposite problem, and maybe even worse because there's no marker to warn people something is different.  I guess I'll just hit control-Z and use cat from the console..

Comment: I assumed it was although I've never used `ipython` in my life.  Sometimes the fancy stuff is just too much for me.  (I still use `emacs` as my editor :-) ...  `!shell command` works the same way in `gnuplot`.  In these situations, I usually just check out the output myself and post it separately with no mention of how I actually inspected it.  I don't know what the best way to do it is though ...  (+1 for pandas btw.  Someday I'll learn this magical package ...)

Comment: Wow, the pandas package is incredible. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow-up question: How can I handle the case where file 2 has the same column headers as file 1? That is, files 1 and 2 both contain [coordinates, data1, data2] and I wish to output [coordinates, data1, data2, data3, data4], where data 1/2 are from file 1 and data 3/4 are from file 2?

Comment: @user2232814: simply tell it you want to merge on the coordinate columns, i.e. `combined = df1.merge(df2, on=list(df1.columns[:2]), how='outer').fillna(0)`.  It'll automatically append suffixes to the `data 1` and `data 2` columns so they don't collide.  You can change the column names if you want by assigning to `combined.columns` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use a `defaultdict` for something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain   

d = defaultdict(lambda:[0,0,0,0])
with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2:
    next(f1) #get rid of header info
    next(f2)
    for line1,line2 in zip(f1,f2):
        data1 = [int(x) for x in line1.split(',')]
        data2 = [int(x) for x in line2.split(',')]
        d[tuple(data1[:2])][:2] = data1[2:]
        d[tuple(data2[:2])][2:] = data2[2:]

#now sort the items and write them out:
#This puts them in stdout, but you could easily use `file.write` here.
for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
    print(', '.join(str(x) for x in chain(k,v)))
```

Comment: I think you'd need `chain.from_iterable` or a `*` to flatten the output, no?

Comment: @DSM -- Not using a `tuple` to begin with would probably be the smartest move :).  I fixed it.  (That's what happens when I go to a conference for a week)